# Unable to print DB value from backend in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, frontend, laravel-blade

I'm developing frontend for a songs website and I'm getting songs from backend like this;

```
{
"songs": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Song title",
            "image": [
                "image.jpeg"
            ],
            "audio": [
                "audio.mp3"
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
 }
```

When I try to print `{{ $song->title }}` it gets printed properly but the `{{ asset("storage/images/$song->image" }}` get printed with `["image.jpeg"]`. Is there a way to strip them on frontend?

Comment: The front-end should include the url of the path where the songs are being stored.

Comment: ex: `site.test/uploads/$image` so, hardcode the url, and use the variable to put it on the url.

Comment: are there supposed to be multiple 'image' and multiple 'audio' ... if not then they should not be in an array

Comment: As you're getting an array as the `image` field, try using this: `{{ asset("storage/images/${song->image[0]}" }}`

Comment: image name inside array so u can use `$song->image[0]`

Comment: @DanielLogvin The storage url is not the issue. The variable of image when gets echo get printed like site.test/uploads/["image.jpeg"] . I want to remove the [""] from the image.jpeg.

Comment: @lagbox no it is just one image that gets appended to the song table from the image table.

Comment: @kraph yes that has solved the problem.

Comment: so why is it appended as an array?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Yes that worked. Thank you.

Comment: @lagbox because the backend developer developed an image table and calling it morphing. The image gets plucked from another table. I'm not sure why it's get appended other than coming from another table.

Comment: sure but it shouldn't be an array, since there won't be many of them ... that should be fixed ... but at least you can move forward now :-) ... good luck and have fun

Comment: @lagbox I agree.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved as suggested by @kraph

```
{{ asset("storage/images/${song->image[0]}") }}
```

Thank you all.